# Unpivot postgres table having multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pivot

I want to pivot a table having some columns like below.

| ID | week1 | week2 | week3 | week4 | week5 | week6 | week7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 2 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |
| 3 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 |

The desired output is -

| ID | week_number | week_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 2 | 9 |
| 1 | 3 | 10 |
| 1 | 4 | 11 |
| 1 | 5 | 12 |
| 1 | 6 | 13 |
| 1 | 7 | 14 |
| 2 | 1 | 15 |
| 2 | 2 | 16 |
| 2 | 3 | 17 |
| 2 | 4 | 18 |
| 2 | 5 | 19 |
| 2 | 6 | 20 |
| 2 | 7 | 21 |
| 3 | 1 | 22 |
| 3 | 2 | 23 |
| 3 | 3 | 24 |
| 3 | 4 | 25 |
| 3 | 5 | 26 |
| 3 | 6 | 27 |
| 3 | 7 | 28 |

I tried using crosstab but couldn't get it working right. Below is my tried approach -

```
select * from crosstab('select ID,week1, week2,week3,week4,week5,week6,week7 order by ID') as table_name(ID, week_number, week_value);
```

Please can someone help as I don't have much experience in handling complex sql queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with SparkSQL, here's a solution using [`stack`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#stack) function. Applied to your example:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14),
    (2, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21),
    (3, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28)
], ["ID", "week1", "week2", "week3", "week4", "week5", "week6", "week7"])

df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")

spark.sql("""
SELECT  ID,
        stack(7, '1', week1, '2', week2, '3', week3, '4', week4, '5', week5, '6', week6, '7', week7) as (week_number, week_value)
FROM    my_table
""").show()

#+---+-----------+----------+
#| ID|week_number|week_value|
#+---+-----------+----------+
#|  1|          1|         8|
#|  1|          2|         9|
#|  1|          3|        10|
#|  1|          4|        11|
#|  1|          5|        12|
#|  1|          6|        13|
#|  1|          7|        14|
#|  2|          1|        15|
#|  2|          2|        16|
#|  2|          3|        17|
#|  2|          4|        18|
#|  2|          5|        19|
#|  2|          6|        20|
#|  2|          7|        21|
#|  3|          1|        22|
#|  3|          2|        23|
#|  3|          3|        24|
#|  3|          4|        25|
#|  3|          5|        26|
#|  3|          6|        27|
#|  3|          7|        28|
#+---+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually the opposite of a pivot, also known as "unpivot" and can be done using a lateral cross join:

```
select t.id, x.*
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
     values (1, week1), (2, week2), (3, week3), 
            (4, week4), (5, week5), (6, week6), 
            (7, week7)
  ) as x(week_number, week_value)
order by t.id, x.week_number
```

Comment: It's not the join which is lateral, it's a _lateral derived table_.

Comment: @jarlh: well, it's a `cross join` ;)

Comment: getting error -
"Undefined function: 'values'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'

Comment: @hotshot_02: then you are not using Postgres (the code is actually 100% standard ANSI SQL). My query [works with Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5dffcb7d1c20c4a6cdb4acc0b8ea55ea)

Comment: @hotshot_02 The query above works just fine under PG9.5 to PG13. Which is your version?

Comment: i am using it with spark sql actually. I think i may need to add libs

Comment: Well Apache Spark is something different than PostgreSQL

Comment: for spark sql, i think mysql will work. i have to try.

Answer (score 1):

A quick alternative using JSONB that works for any number of colums provided that one of them is called `id`. Unrelated but the result looks alarmingly similar to the infamous [EAV antipattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-it-really-bad-in-all-scenarios).

```sql
with t as (select to_jsonb(t) j from the_table t)
select j ->> 'id' id, 
       (jsonb_each_text(j - 'id')).*
from t;
```

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | week1 | 8 |
| 1 | week2 | 9 |
| 1 | week3 | 10 |
| 1 | week4 | 11 |
| 1 | week5 | 12 |
| 1 | week6 | 13 |
| 1 | week7 | 14 |
| 2 | week1 | 15 |
| 2 | week2 | 16 |
| 2 | week3 | 17 |
| 2 | week4 | 18 |
| 2 | week5 | 19 |
| 2 | week6 | 20 |
| 2 | week7 | 21 |
| 3 | week1 | 22 |
| 3 | week2 | 23 |
| 3 | week3 | 24 |
| 3 | week4 | 25 |
| 3 | week5 | 26 |
| 3 | week6 | 27 |
| 3 | week7 | 28 |

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select t.id
,unnest(array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]) as week_number
,unnest(array[week1, week2, week3, week4, week5, week6, week7]) as week_value
from table1 t;
```